# How to compile a downloaded .zip file

Tags: linux-mint

I've downloaded [this zip file](https://github.com/maffmeier/fprint_vfs5011/archive/master.zip) from GitHub and I need to compile it. I have no idea how to go about the compilation.

Comment: That does not give a `.zip` file when used as following `wget https://github.com/maffmeier/fprint_vfs5011`. So where is the zip file?

Comment: @Anthon he can use the webpage interface to download the whole lib as a zip bundle. Running
./configure && make  
Should do the compilation trick.

Comment: Please check the contents of the file before posting. The zip contains a file called `INSTALL` which explains the steps you need to follow.

Comment: Then why not give a link to the actual zip instead of some web interface where we have to guess what was exactly downloaded. Did the OP get a zip of latest revision, or a zip of the whole git repository?

Comment: This is the zip file: https://github.com/maffmeier/fprint_vfs5011/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 3):

If you have checked out the project there (it is not a .zip file) you have an INSTALL file which helps you:

```
  The simplest way to compile this package is:

  1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type
     `./configure' to configure the package for your system.

     Running `configure' might take a while. While running, it prints
     some messages telling which features it is checking for.

  2. Type `make' to compile the package.

  3. Optionally, type `make check' to run any self-tests that come with
     the package.

  4. Type `make install' to install the programs and any data files and
     documentation.

  5. You can remove the program binaries and object files from the
     source code directory by typing `make clean'. To also remove the
     files that `configure' created (so you can compile the package for
     a different kind of computer), type `make distclean'. There is
     also a `make maintainer-clean' target, but that is intended mainly
     for the package's developers. If you use it, you may have to get
     all sorts of other programs in order to regenerate files that came
     with the distribution.
```

If the project would not have an `INSTALL` file, a good start is reading the `README`.

The above sequence:

```
 ./configure
 make 
 make install
```

is pretty common for projects that you build yourself on Linux. Please note that the last command often requires you to run it as `root` using `sudo make install`.

Comment: I got this at the end of `./configure`.

`checking for LIBUSB... no
 configure: error: Package requirements (libusb-1.0 >=  0.9.1) were not met:

 No package 'libusb-1.0' found

 Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment  variable if you
 installed software in a non-standard prefix.

 Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBUSB_CFLAGS
 and LIBUSB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
 See the pkg-config man page for more details.
`

Comment: @ChinmayaKR make sure libusb-1.0 can be found. If you are on Debian or derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint) I would do `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev`, although `sudo apt-get install libusb` might be enough.

Comment: For Fedora you need to do `sudo yum install libusb1-devel` to resolve the missing dependency.